# How to model multiple data frames in a single function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, functional-programming, tidyverse

I want to create a function that splits a data frame, builds models on each part of the data frame, and appends all the models to a single list. I prefer to do this within one function so I can apply it beyond this project without a lot of pre-processing to the individual data frames.

My non-elegant solution:

```
data(mtcars)

buildModels <- function(dat) {
  
  #Pull out a few slightly different datasets
  train1 <- dat[1:10, 1:3]
  train2 <- dat[11:21, 1:4]
  train3 <- dat[22:32, 1:5]
  
  set.seed(789)
  mod1 <- stats::glm(mpg ~ .,
                     data = train1)
  set.seed(789)
  mod2 <- stats::glm(mpg ~ .,
                     data = train2)
  set.seed(789)
  mod3 <- stats::glm(mpg ~ .,
                     data = train3)
  
  assign(paste0(deparse(substitute(dat)), "modlist"),
         list(mod1, mod2, mod3),
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

buildModels(mtcars)
#output is correct, a list called "mtcardsmodlist"
```

How can I use a for loop, lapply, etc. to automatically build these models in the function? I was able to create a list of datasets (ie `list(train1, train2, train3)`) but I am having a hard time assigning each model to an object so I can add them to the model list.

Really I am just looking for a way to streamline what I'm doing here. My example uses base R but I am open to a tidyverse solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply replace in your function everything below the `set.seed(789)` row (I'm not sure what that row is for) with:

```
  v = list("glm_train1" = train1, "glm_train2" = train2, "glm_train3" = train3)
  lapply(v, \(df) stats::glm(mpg ~ .,data = df))
```

and then assign the result when you call the function (not in the function itself)

```
models = buildmodels(data)
```

Output (`models`):

```
$glm_train1

Call:  stats::glm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl         disp  
  30.068791    -1.623941    -0.001342  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  7 Residual
Null Deviance:      76.06 
Residual Deviance: 19.59    AIC: 43.1

$glm_train2

Call:  stats::glm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp  
  37.354233    -0.284274    -0.006436    -0.096132  

Degrees of Freedom: 10 Total (i.e. Null);  7 Residual
Null Deviance:      717.9 
Residual Deviance: 102.5    AIC: 65.77

$glm_train3

Call:  stats::glm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          cyl         disp           hp         drat  
  51.052289    -4.246153     0.018713     0.002739    -2.445941  

Degrees of Freedom: 10 Total (i.e. Null);  6 Residual
Null Deviance:      330.8 
Residual Deviance: 52.27    AIC: 60.36
```

Comment: The use of set.seed() may not be necessarily for glm, but it is necessary to make some of the more stochastic models I'm building reproducible. I just added it to the first line under the lapply().

Comment: sure, you can do that. see edit

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for` loop on the list of dataframes like so:

```
dfList <- list(train1, train2, train3)

for (name in names(dflist)){
    buildModels(dflist[[name]])
}
```

Comment: I am hoping for a function that basically runs the for loop within it. I believe using this method I would have to build the function, then run it in the loop and individually assign the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `do.call` function for simplicity.

```
 buildModels <- function(dat) {

   df_train <- 
     list(
     train1 = dat[1:10, 1:3],
     train2 = dat[11:21, 1:4],
     train3 = dat[22:32, 1:5]
     )

  modlist <- 
    do.call(
    list, 
    lapply(df_train, \(df) stats::glm(mpg ~ ., data = df))
    )

 return(modlist)
 }
```